# Запрос к таблице БД в Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Есть два вопроса к выборке данных из БД. Сначала кратко опишу связь таблиц.

Есть таблица customers - покупатели и region - регион. Связаны они так customers.id = region.customersID.

Есть TableView, в который нужно выводить информацию о покупателях в виде Фио покупателя, Адрес и Регион. Регион хранится в отдельной таблице region.

Вопрос 1: Для того чтобы вытащить данные из этих таблиц нужно написать класс, который будет описывать нужные поля из обеих таблиц customers и region или как в таком случае действуют? Ведь в классе модели в Hibernate можно описать только одну таблицу в аннотации @Table(name = "customers")

Вопрос 2: Есть множество мелких справочников, к которым нужно делать запросы, при использовании Hibernate надо ли создавать отдельные классы, описывающие каждую таблицу или можно на HQL писать запросы напрямую обращаясь к таблицам БД?

Comment: Не хватает кода классов Сustomer и Region - как там описан отношение. customers.id = region.customersID выглядит подозрительно, казалось бы должно быть наоборот.

Comment: Отношение не описывала. Они сейчас отдельные классы. А отношение обязательно указывать в Hibernate?

Comment: Hibernate - инструмент, лучше бы его применять правильно. Я правильно понимаю, что аннотации ManyToOne / OneToMany не использовались?

Comment: Да, не использовались. Обязательно ли их использовать? И что если одна таблица связана с несколькими таблицами, а не с одной? Например таблица customers связана с region, orders, addreses, payments. Для всех связок нужно использовать эти аннотации?

Comment: Краткий ответ - да.